# What is the difference between numerator and denominator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The sum of the numerator and denominator of a positive fraction is 11. If 2 is added to
both numerator and denominator, the fraction is increased by 1/24. What is the difference
between the numerator and denominator of the fraction?

Do we have any shortcuts for questions like these?

Comment: The difference is...what?

Comment: we have to find it

Comment: Ok, makes sense. You might want to rephrase to "What is the difference between the num and the den?"

Comment: We know a+b=11, (a+2)/(b+2)=a/b+1/24. Can you do the rest from here?

Comment: Posting your current solution may help to know what is considered as "shortcutted" and what's not.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest solution that I’ve found is to write the fraction as $\frac{a}b$ and note that

$$\frac1{24}=\frac{a+2}{b+2}-\frac{a}b=\frac{2(b-a)}{b(b+2)}\;,$$

so

$$\frac{b-a}{b(b+2)}=\frac1{48}\;.$$

$6\cdot8=48$, so try $b=6$; then $a=5$, which works.

Replacing $a$ by $11-b$ to get

$$\frac{13-b}{b+2}=\frac{11-b}b+\frac1{24}=\frac{264-23b}{24b}$$

and solving the resulting quadratic $24b(13-b)=(b+2)(264-23b)$ for $b$ confirms that this is the only solution. However, it’s hardly a general technique, unlike the solution of the quadratic.

Answer (score 2):

If the numerator and denominator are supposed to be positive integers that sum to $11$, there are only $10$ possibilities, and it's pretty easy to check them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

With the fraction $\ds{p \over q}$ we get
$\ds{47q - 48 p = q\pars{q + 1}}$. Since $q\pars{q + 1}$ and $48p$ are even, $q$ must be even. We only have to check $q = 2, 4, 6, 8 , 10$ such that
$$
p = {q\pars{46 - q} \over 48} = {s\pars{23 - s} \over 12}
\quad
\mbox{is an integer}\,,
\quad
q= 2s\,,\quad s = 1,2,3,4,5
$$ 
That yields the allowed $s = 3\quad\imp\quad q = 6,\quad p = 5\imp\quad$
$\ds{\large{p \over q} = {5 \over 6}}$

Comment: We can also infer that $q>p$ from the fact that both are positive and that adding a positive value to both increases the fraction, so we only have to check $q=6,8,10$.

Comment: @JaycobColeman Fine. That's true. Since the "range" was quite small we didn't pay attention to that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{x}{y}=\dfrac{x+a}{y+a}+b=\dfrac{x+a+by+ba}{y+a}$

$xa=ya+by^2+bay$

$x=y+by\dfrac{y+a}{a}$

$x+y=n$

$n=y(b\dfrac{y+a}{a}+2)=\dfrac{b}ay^2+(b
+2)y$,

so

$y=\dfrac{-(b+2)\pm \sqrt{(b+2)^2+4bn/a}}{2b/a}$

Yours is the particular case $a=2,b=-1/24,n=11$. This gives two solutions, but one can be cast out as it would require one of $x,y$ to be negative, which would make the fraction negative as well.